# Alternitives to C like labling and escaping nested loops for C++

Tags: c++, closures, try-catch, goto

In C and in javascript I enjoy the ability to write this kind of thing and have it just work.

```
while (a)
{
ctx: while(b)
     {
         while (c)
         {
             if(d) break ctx;
             ...
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

Perhaps I'm just confused about C++ versions but I get this kind of error in g++:

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ctx’
     break ctx;
error: ‘ctx’ was not declared in this scope
warning: label ‘ctx’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 ctx:
```

C++ appears to refuse letting me write this code.
C++ has added lambdas/closures that potentially would let me do this but I'm not quite sure how they would work in this case.

Using try throw catch is the closest construct I can think of that produces this behavior but the sloppiness of using an error system when none should be needed concerns me (Also they are slow I hear).

I'm tempted to just wrap it in extern C except I'm relying on c++ library's completely for the entire project so this also feels sloppy.

Is a try block or just rewriting my only options?

Comment: I was able to use goto to solve this... I though it was a banned construct in c++?

Comment: My advice is to stop trying to make C++ look like some other language.  All you did by using `goto` is potentially make spaghetti code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate the tip, I wouldn't have asked otherwise. I just assumed goto woldn't compile in my question and I was wrong. which only adds to my concerns.

Comment: Well, `goto` exists in C++.  Just don't overuse it.  If you're using it to simply break out of a nested loop, then it could be justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ have a labelled break statement (You're probably using a language extension, rather than standard C).

Instead, you can use `goto` to break out of a nested loop.

```
while (a)
{
    while(b)
    {
        while (c)
        {
            if(d)
                goto break_b;
        }
    }
    break_b:
    // ...
}
```

> I was able to use goto to solve this... I though it was a banned construct in c++?

No. `goto` is not "banned" in C++.

This is a completely fine way to use `goto`. There doesn't exist an equivalent structured control statement.

---

> lambdas/closures [...] potentially would let me do this but I'm not quite sure how they would work in this case.

If you are allergic to `goto`, then you can indeed use a lambda, but I don't see it providing any additional readability:

```
while (a)
{
    [&](){
        while(b)
        {
            while (c)
            {
                if(d)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }();
    // ...
}
```

Instead of a lambda, you can use a named function. But in that case you need to pass any variables (such as `b`, `c` and `d`) as arguments (assuming they're not globals).

---

Yet another way is an extra variable:

```
while (a)
{
    bool break_b = false;
    while(b)
    {
        while (c)
        {
            if(d) {
                break_b = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (break_b)
            break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Of these three methods, I recommend `goto`, since it's the most readable. Except in the case the actual inner loop omitted from the example is very long, in which case a separate function might be better.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out by others, `goto` would be a way to do exactly what you're asking for.

That being said, I would argue that, before asking the question of how to break out of a massively-complicated control flow structure, you should first ask yourself why there is a massively-complicated flow structure to begin with. What is going on in these loops? Should whatever is going on in each of these loops not better be moved into its own function? For example, instead of

```
while (a)
{
ctx: while (b)
     {
         while (c)
         {
             if (d) goto ctx;
             …
         }
     }
     …
}
```

why not

```
bool doC()
{
    while (c)
    {
        if (d)
            return false;
        …
    }

    return true;
}

void doB()
{
    while (b && doC());
}
```

and then

```
while (a)
{
    doB();
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the break with a goto here is not advisable. There can be issues wrt constructors and destructors not being called correctly. Whilst goto still exists in C++, it's really not something you want to use unless you *really* know what you're doing! A safer option would be to use a try-catch block. A better approach would be to re-factor your algorithm *(currently it's O(N^3), which should really be ringing some alarm bells!)*

```
while (a)
{
  try
  {
    while(b)
    {
      while (c)
      {
        if(d) throw;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(...)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would there be *issues wrt constructors and destructors not being called correctly*?

Comment: *"There can be issues wrt constructors and destructors not being called correctly."* No there cannot be such issues, [\[stmt.dcl\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#stmt.dcl-3) makes sure of that. A program that would try to do something that would give rise to such issues is required to fail to compile…

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is a bit icky, exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances